# Sequelize: Write multidimensional array to database

Tags: mysql, json, node.js, sequelize.js

I have a JSON file with nested arrays of varying length. That is, each object has an ARR with a different number of objects.

```
   {    "count": 200,
        "objects": [
            {
                "id": "FIRST",
                "b": "two",
                "c": "three",
                "ARR": [{
                    "aa": "onion ",
                    "bb": 2,
                    "cc": "peanuts"},
                    },
                    {
                    "aa": "Jam ",
                    "bb": 4,
                    "cc": "Bread"},
                    }],
                 "d":"four"
                ]
            }, . . . on and on
```

I have imported the JSON data to my JavaScript file:

```
 const data = JSON.parse(require('fs').readFileSync('./jsonfiles/objects.JSON', 'utf8'))
```

trim data down to the objects of interest

```
const objs=data.objects;
```

I'm using Sequelize to write this to a mysql database. I have two models: Model 1: hasMany Arr sets: Model 2: belongsTo Model1.

Writing the to table1 from Model1 works well like this:

```
for (var key in Objs) {
var item = Objs[key]
db.Model1.create({
    modelID: item.id,
    modelB: item.b,
    modelC:item.c
 })
}
```

Now, I'm trying to write ARR to the associated model and am stumped on how to do this.

- I do not know how many objects will be in each ARR
- Storing ARR as a JSON obj in table1 won't serve well later.

Comment: There is missing array braces in ARR, so pls validate the json first

Comment: Hi @VinuBibin, There are indeed square brackets around those objects in my JSON file.

Answer (score 0):

This is the function I created for our companies API. Took me a week to put together but hopefully, this helps.

```js
exports.functionName = async (req, res) => {

    const params = req.params.something;

    
    if (!params) {
        res.status(httpStatusCodes.BAD_REQUEST).send({message:'Please provide params'});
        return;
    }

    const function =  inputs.map(prop => ({
        propOne: uniqueID,
        propTwo: prop.value,
    }));

    const value = await productInput.bulkCreate(function);

    if (!value || value.length < 1) {
        res.status(httpStatusCodes.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).send({ message:'No inputs were updated for this product.' });
        return;
    }

    res.send(value);
    return;
};
```